# Is decomposing the middle third Cantor set doable paradoxically?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I was just curious, is it possible to break the middle third Cantor set $C$ into a finite number of pieces, and after rearranging them, obtaining a "larger" set, i.e. perhaps in terms of Lebesgue measure? Has this even been attempted as yet?

Comment: This question [Banach-Tarski Paradox on the middle third Cantor set](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92980/banach-tarski-paradox-on-the-middle-third-cantor-set)  seems to be related.

Comment: You might be interested in the types of sets discussed here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kakeya_set namely, sets in R² containing unit line segments of every angle, but with Lebesgue measure 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible as asked, because the Cantor set has measure zero; *every* subset of a measure zero set is Lebesgue measurable with measure zero; the "rearranging" operations would preserve measure; and a finite or countable union of measure zero sets still has measure zero.

Comment: But what if we imposed a different sort of measure on $C$, would that make any difference?

Comment: @Sachin, unless you state some limitation on the measure anything is possible. For example the Cantor set is equinumerous with a ball in $\mathbb R^3$, so you could carry over the measure (and isometries) from that, and use the Banach-Tarski decomposition.

Answer (score 2):

For the ordinary Cantor set, it is not possible, since the Cantor set has Lebesgue measure $0$. But what about "fat" Cantor sets?

Again, the answer is that it cannot be done, but the reason is different. There is a **finitely additive** translation-invariant "measure" on all sets of reals that extends Lebesgue measure. That "measure" prevents paradoxical decompositions of the Banach-Tarski type on the line.